# How do I execute a node function using nodewebkit and Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, node-webkit

I'm experimenting with node webkit. I wanted to make a simple page where you have a link with a torrent url, you click it and that calls a function to start streaming the torrent with [peerflix](https://github.com/mafintosh/peerflix).

I'm using angular so I thought using ng-click to execute a function inside the scope of the controller that calls the peerflix module but I just can't get it to work.

I have the dependency and can require it correctly, but I'm sure I'm missing something about using node modules and calling them through angular while on nodewebkit.

Can anybody give me a hand?

Comment: Include some code of what your trying narrow down what is failing as is this is too broad.

Comment: never mind. I found a way around it by not using angular to call the function. It's actually better cause I'm using angular for the "web app" and leaving it out of the external function.